# Will sin(n) ever meet 0?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, natural-numbers

We know that $\pi$ is an irrational number, which has infinite number of digits.
At the other side we know that the set of Natural numbers($\mathbb{N}$), is an infinite set,
I wanted to know if ever numbers of $N$ ever become devisable by $\pi$ number?!
Or in the other words, does $sin(n)$ ever meet $zero$?

> p.s. This questions came from another question where it wanted to ask is $n \in O(|n^2sin(n)|)$ ?

I will appreciate you if you also provide a proof with your answer.

Comment: $\sin n=0$ if and only if $n$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Depends on you definitions, but frequently $0\in \mathbb N.$  Excepting this case, no there is no $n\in \mathbb N-\{0\}$ such that $\pi$ divides $n.$  There will be values of $n$ where $\sin n$ is arbitrarily close to $0$ but not equal to $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}*$ so that $sin(n) = 0$, then $\exists k \in\mathbb{N}*$, so that $n = 0 +k\pi$, then $\pi = \frac{n}{k}$, which would mean $\pi \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is absurd. In other word there is no such $n$. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Altough for n = 0, sin(n) = 0

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. @user310148

Comment: By the way what do you think about the 'p.s' part? @user310148

Comment: can you link me said question, I have trouble understanding what it means. Maybe we are using different notations.

Comment: it is about the [$Big-O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). @user31048

Comment: Well yea, I understand what it means, but what I dont get is how can n belong to 0(|sin(n)n²|. Its not a set ? Or do you mean if n = 0(|sin(n)n²|. Is the question posted somewhere ? So i can answer directly

Comment: Excuse me but the question is not anywhere and it is a question in our exam.Yes your assumption is true and I want to know if n = O(|sin(n)n²|)? @user310148